# Simple J2ee program is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

[this is structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWVta.png)**This servlet is placed in servlets package**

```
package Servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class OpenAccountServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        String firstName=request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastName=request.getParameter("lastname");
        String fatherName=request.getParameter("fathername");
        String webPage=null;
        webPage+="<html>";
        webPage+="<head>";
        webPage+="</head>";
        webPage+="<body>";
        webPage+=firstName;
        webPage+=lastName;
        webPage+=fatherName;
        webPage+="</body>";
        webPage+="</html>";
        out.println(webPage);
        out.close();
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        doGet(request,response);
    }
    public void destroy(){

    }
}
```

**this is jsp page which i am using for accepting data from user.**

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="openaccount.do">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
          <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**and this is my web.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Open_Account_controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlets.OpenAccountServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Open_Account_controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/openaccount.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and whenever i am trying to run this, 404 error. i am using intelliJ idea IDE for development, and i am using 64 bit tomcat.

Comment: what url makes you 404?

Comment: its is like this http://localhost:8080/WebAppName/openaccount.do.................. after submitting form saying resource not found

Comment: what is your jsp page's path? its it localhost:8080/WebAppName/index.jsp?

Comment: yes its like this                 localhost:8080/WebAppName/index.jsp

Comment: you may need to post you project structure and intelliJ config in the question description. Also, the package name should be lower case, try replace Servlets` into 'servlets' and restart tomcat before you do that

Comment: I have given it and settings are ok of my intelliJ because its index page is working and no error is showing tomcat server.

Comment: i have also make servlet package in lowercase.still not working

Comment: I think that /openaccount.do is not a valid url. Try using just /openaccount or /

Answer (score 0):

Try `<form method="post" action="../openaccount.do">`
When you remove the leading `../` It would try to load the url relative to current directory.

Better yet use a more generic form like:
`action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/openaccount.do"`

Comment: actually for tomcat server 8, url-mapping is not working properly. if i use **/servlet/*** in DD and **servlet/servlet1** in form **action** attribute, in tomcat server 7 there will not be any problem. the tomcat server can find the jsp resources well. But for the same , tomcat server 8 could not find the right path for the jsp's. is there any changes happened in tomcat server 8 release?

Comment: @Aniket No changes that would affect the URL mapping as far as I know. If the same code does not work in tomcat 8, what exactly happens does it give 404 when you submit the form? what about if you enter the servlet url directly into the browser?

Comment: OK let me collet all the answers of your questions. Then I will response here.thanks for your help!